# Add java argument to windows right click?

Tags: windows, registry

I have a jar which takes file path and file name as Input.

I want to make an option wherein I right click any file in windows --> I see a say "send to java" option.

Clicking on that passes my filename and filepath to jar as an argument and also run the jar.

Comment: Not entirely sure if Java is really the right language for this.

Comment: That is not a java question, this has to be solved in the windows registry.